# ReportViewer printing questions

Tags: c#, printing, report-viewer2010

1. Is there a way to autofit a report to the chosen paper type when printing?
2. I'm trying to print my report in a landscape mode, and even tohugh I set the paper properties to "landscape" and the report itself is set to be landscape - It is still printed in Portait mode.   what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the default printer settings under windows if that fails u may have to set length and width of the report manually in code.